# Recursion in C++ in a linear linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am having some troubles adding to a LLL using recursion. What I am attempting to do is count how many nodes there are in a LLL and then add a new node at the end of the list with that count value. An LLL has already been set up and it automatically creates a random sized LLL of integers. Any help would be appreciated as I clearly have a flaw in my thinking. Thank you.

```
#include "list.h"


int wrapper_add_end(node* head)
{
    if(!head) return 0;

    if(head->next != NULL)
        return count_add_end(head->next);
}

int count_add_end(node*& head)
{
    int count = 0;

    if(!head) return 0;

    if(head->next != NULL)
    {
        count += count_add_end(head->next) + 1;
    }

    node* temp = new node;
    if(head->next == NULL)
    {
        temp = head->next;
        temp->data = count;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return 1;
    }

    return count_add_end(head->next);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers. If someone needs to compile your code then they have to delete the numbers from each line.

Comment: Lines 33 and 21 duplicate the recursive call. Maybe you just wanted to return at line 21.

Comment: You construct a new node. Then, if you don't need it, you keep it, and if you do need it, you throw it away. The first is a memory leak, the second is a memory leak *and* Undefined Behavior.

Comment: `temp = head->next;` you got the assignment in the wrong direction meaning it should be `head->next = temp;`

Comment: None of your code calls 'wrapper_add_end(node*)".  Remove it?  Please review [mre].  For us to help, we need to be able to reproduce your error.  This code does not compiler.

Comment: `wrapper_add_end()` also broken if the passed `head` is null because unlike `count_add_end()` it passes the pointer by value.